# Getting 'Headers already sent' with TCPDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

EDIT 2: The problem is not solved; I found a work around by switching to an older version of the file, which was using ezpdf instead of TCPDF, and altering it to get the desired printout (I don't know why only one page in the entire website was changed to TCPDF, but apparently it happened).  I would still like to know if there is a way to fix this problem, as the code for TCPDF functions correctly on the server running php 5.2, but not the new server.  However, it no longer remains a major priority.

After submitting a request for a PDF, I get nothing; just a blank page. This is all code taken from another server (we are updating php versions to 5.3) and the code works fine on the first server.

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent (output started at filepath in path/tcpdf.php)
>   **TCPDF ERROR:** Some data has already been output to browser, can't send PDF file

After some debugging, I noticed that the problem is a 'headers already sent error', 
which I've encountered several times while updating this site.  Most of these errors are fixable using `meta http-equiv`, as they are mostly just page-refreshes.  However, TCPDF uses headers to make the PDF file and force a download.

How can I get case 'D' to work, without needing headers, and if it can't be done, can case 'I' be altered to work without headers instead?

I have tried using `ob_clean()` before `$pdf->output()`. I have also tried removing `require_once('./common/tcpdf/config/lang/eng.php')`. Both of these have fixed problems for other people, and I have extensively researched the topic.  I do not think it will work in this case, because I am aware that the website has already started output at this point.

What I want is an alternative to using headers (meta http-equiv?) in case 'D' (preferable) or case 'I' (doable) in the code below, that will give me the same results (a pdf download or a pdf opened in a new tab or window).  Unless, of course, there is another fix.  If not, I will have to re-write the page without using TCPDF.

EDIT: On the original server, 'generate pdf' causes the page to reload and then, after a long wait (while it queries the database), it forces a download on the user.  On the new server, the page is reloaded, the long wait for the query occurs, and then the menu actually breaks (log out is removed and another button is moved beneath the rest of the menu bar) and nothing else happens.

Code taken from tcpdf.php:

```
case 'I': {
                // Send PDF to the standard output
                echo "<script>console.log('some log');</script>";
                if (ob_get_contents()) {
                    $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
                }
                if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
                    //We send to a browser
                    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                    if (headers_sent()) {
                        $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
                    }
                    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
                    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');  
                    header('Content-Length: '.$this->bufferlen);
                    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($name).'";');
                }
                echo $this->getBuffer();
                break;
            }
                case 'D': {
                    // Download PDF as file
                    if (ob_get_contents()) {
                        $this->Error('Some data has already been output, can\'t send PDF file');
                    }
                    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                    if (headers_sent()) {

                        $this->Error('Some data has already been output to browser, can\'t send PDF file');
                    }
                    header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
                    header('Pragma: public');
                    header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
                    header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
                    // force download dialog
                    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
                    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream', false);
                    header('Content-Type: application/download', false);
                    header('Content-Type: application/pdf', false);
                    // use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename
                    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($name).'";');
                    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                    header('Content-Length: '.$this->bufferlen);
                    echo $this->getBuffer();
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Is this happening in the context of a particular PHP framework or CMS?

Comment: yes, it is supposed to generate a pdf report as part of league management software.  the pdf generation happens after the website has loaded, which is why the headers can no longer be sent.

Comment: It should tell you what script and what line was responsible for the output that prevents headers from being sent.

Comment: It says there is output started on administration.php:366.  Line 366 of that file only has '<?', there is no output.  There is an entire section of html above that, which would be output.  However, I still don't know how to fix the location of the headers in the tcpdf file to make sure they are called before that output is started.  That is why I was hoping for an alternative to the headers instead.

Comment: Odds are there is some white space before the `<?`. Also, you should generally use `<?php `

Comment: This had occurred to me as a possibility.  The problem is there are many, many php files being included on any one page in this system.  If there was white space, it could be anywhere.  Also, I can guarantee that there is output other than white space; this is why I was hoping for an alternative to header to create and force the php download, because prior output is not something I can avoid.  Lastly, this code is going on 11 years old; part of the change to the new server has involved using <?php instead of <?, but there are hundreds of files and it hasn't been a priority.

Comment: We would need to see administration.php to answer this, and you'd need to say whether the PDF is being created within that page or whether that page is being (incorrectly?) included by the page that _is_ creating the PDF. Essentially you need to ensure that, whatever is outputting something, it does not output anything at all when a PDF is being created. If the "something" is a great wodge of HTML, then this needs to be traced and prevented (perhaps by adding logic to prevent an include? Not possible to say at present). Also, make sure you `exit()` after the download.

Comment: I can't show you administration.php, but I can describe it.  It features a php section up until line 227, after which it goes through the html and head tags, and starts the body (up until the navigation menu is completed) after this it enters into another php section (this is where firefox said 'output started').  The html tags are the output that it is detecting, which is what I don't think I can avoid (and the code worked correctly on the original server as it is).  Because I don't think the output can be avoided, I was hoping to modify tcpdf.php with alternatives to header() instead.

Comment: That said, preventing the page from loading if a pdf is being created might be possible; however, the rest of the website uses other methods for pdf generation (not tcpdf) and therefore they don't use headers (they just generate links to new pages), so if I have to I will imitate them for this page as well.

Comment: You do not need to touch the class `tcpdf.php`. You just need to call `ob_start();` in the beginning of your script.

Comment: Interesting. I have the opposite problem. Same script runs fine on 5.3 but not on server with 5.2

Comment: CORRECTION: Well, it is more than that. I am running version 4.8 on the 5.3 server and v6.2 on the 5.2 server.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen a lot of references around the Web to use ob_start(), with ob_end_flush() at the end of file.
Maybe that works in some situations, although I really don't understood how it would. Not disagreeing - just saying I don't understand, and I did not find it as a solution to the problem.

However, I have found that using ob_start() at the top of the file and ob_end_clean() BEFORE the output should do the trick.

```
<?PHP
    ob_start();
    // All other content
    ob_end_clean();
    $pdf->Output('MyPDF_File.pdf', 'D');
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

add

```
code ob_start()
```

in  early function and ob_end_flush(); after $pdf->output()

Comment: This post was automatically flagged because of its length. Could you please elaborate and explain your answer?

Comment: I have been using `tcpdf` for years now. Just open the buffer in the beginning of your script should be enough. This answer should be considered as right one.

Answer (score 1):

There's an echo before setting the header.
Just remove:

```
echo "<script>console.log('some log');</script>";
```

There may not be eny echo or print before ending the header

Comment: I inserted that echo during debugging to make sure the code was reaching that line.  It had no effect on end result other than logging 'some log' to the console.  Removing it just now also had no effect on the end result.

Comment: I think you mean before *starting* the header

Comment: I understand the thinking here, that the echo is the output preventing the header from working.  Again, however, removing it doesn't help, as there is other output before that echo.  I'm not trying to remove previous output, I'm looking for a way to create the pdf and either open it in a new window/tab, or force a download, without using header() at all.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, go to the file called as "tcpdf_static.php" from the tcpdf vendor folder, and in function sendOutputData, replace echo $data with following lines to resolve the issue

```
ob_start();        
ob_end_clean();// All other content        
echo $data;
ob_end_flush();
die;
```

Hope it helps